# Meijer's G-function differentiation

Tags: special-functions

I am trying to calculate the derivative of the Meijer's G function, Based on wolfram function identities I have found in (07.34.20.0003.01) that the derivative is expressed asl:
$\frac{d}{dx}G^{m,n}_{p,q}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}a_1,\ldots,a_p\\b_1,\ldots,b_q\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)=G^{m,n}_{p,q}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}a_1-1,\ldots,a_p\\b_1,\ldots,b_q\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)+(a_1-1)G^{m,n}_{p,q}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}a_1,\ldots,a_p\\b_1,\ldots,b_q\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)$

However I have found in Some handbooks such as ("Abramowitz and Stegun "Table of integrals") that a missing x should be multiplied with the left side of the identity:
$x\frac{d}{dx}G^{m,n}_{p,q}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}a_1,\ldots,a_p\\b_1,\ldots,b_q\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)=G^{m,n}_{p,q}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}a_1-1,\ldots,a_p\\b_1,\ldots,b_q\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)+(a_1-1)G^{m,n}_{p,q}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}a_1,\ldots,a_p\\b_1,\ldots,b_q\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)$

I don't know which one is the correct identity, can we demonstrate it. Please help.

Comment: did you show [The_hypergeometric_differential_equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation) and [Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Differentiation) ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is an error on Wolfram. This is not that uncommon unfortunately.

Comment: I found in the book of Harry Batmen (1953) "HIGHER TRANSCENDENTAL FUNCTIONS" volume 1 the same identity as "Tables of integrals, series, and products" Daniel Zwillinger (2007). So I'm sure that the identity of Wolfram is false. Thanks